# Passing text from PROGMEM to function in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to pass a string stored in Program Memory to a function, and then compare it to the string last passed to the same function (this is in Arduino). The length of the string may vary. In the function, I want to print only if the new string passed is NOT the same as the last string. I've been reading on this but totally stumped.

PSEUDO CODE

```
Demoprint(F("new command"));

Void Demoprint(...variable or string here. NewText){
   If (NewText != oldText) {
       Serial.print(NewText);
    }
    oldText = NewText;
   }
}

//or
const PROGMEM char1[] = "This is line 1 of code";
const PROGMEM char2[] = "This is line 2 of text";

Demoprint(char1);
```

Any suggestions on the way to do this? The pointer *, dereferencing, passing parameters to functions, etc. This is confusing to me, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use String data type instead of char array.
2. Strings can be compared to eachother with equals() function
3. You can store string passed to the function previously in a static variable inside of a function. It will store value between calls.

So, you function can look like:

```cpp
void myprint(String s)
{
    static String prev_s = "";
    if (!prev_s.equals(s))
    {
        Serial.print(s);
        prev_s = s;
    }
}

//Testing:
myprint("String 1");
myprint("String 1");
myprint("String 1");
myprint("String 2");
```

You should get in result:

```
String 1
String 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  if these strings are stored in ProgMEM, how would that change the routine.
    const char* PROGMEM test = "First String in Flash mem";
    const char* PROGMEM test2 = "2nd string  in Flash mem";
    const char* PROGMEM test3 = "3rd Strin Flash mem";

and no restriction on the length of each string...?

Comment: PROGMEM could work with static in-function variables, so you should try, it have to works. There are examples of using PROGMEM to store strings in official arduino docs, so, this must be working method.